# Can I connect a DC-DC step-up converter to a DC-DC step-down converter in series?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

My problem is I need 3A at 5V from an 18650 cell.

I bought a DC-DC converter that should do that, but they are garbage specifically the XL6009 it seems that they'd prefer to operate in high voltage vs. low. They come around 40V stock and when I try to turn them down... most won't go lower than 18V.

So... what if I use one to step up to whatever voltage (where it doesn't change over time, I noticed that) and I use a similar DC-DC converter but step down eg. LM2596, will I be okay or is there going to be a situation where they're fighting each other?

The reason for the 18650/3A is for a multi-servo robot.

Comment: The [XL6009 Datasheet](https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf) specifies a minimum input voltage of 5V. I'm surprised you get anything at all with one of those and a single 18650 cell.

Comment: I got them from Amazon it says 3V-32V to 5V-35V... and I bought two different sellers and yeah... the main concern I had is you had to turn the potentiometer so far to get it from 40V+ down to 5... and I could it watch it slowly rise up/down... anyway I bought the wrong thing, bought a dedicated part that I also notice costs 10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the currents and voltages are compatible, you can use the output of the step up converter as an input for the step down converter.

However, it is not very efficient (you need 2 converter on your robot, each one having usually arroud 20% energy loss (if not more if you take cheap ones).

So I would rather suggest either to use a step up dedicated to go from 2.7-4.2V to 5V (there should be plenty, as it is used for example for powerbanks, or all other applications requiring 5V from a single lithium cell).

Or you can go the other way arround, and take a 2S or 3S Lipo and a step down converter

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. I tried to buy one (3.7V to 5V @ 3A), that was the one I Found XL6009 unless you have a better one in mind? Maybe I need to look at a real electronics store like Mouser.

Comment: @JacobDavidC.Cunningham -- The step-down controller is really good idea, because you'll want the better power output anyway, and if you can't depend on the converters you are saying are garbage, then make a strong decision not to build a robot on such questionable technology. You're just asking for trouble by staying with garbage.

Comment: Yeah I found these I will try these out. mEZD41503A-A They look to be exactly what I want eg. single cell input, 5V @ 3A out. I just designed/built the robot to use a single cell battery so that's why I'm hung up on this spec.

Comment: Well my fate is sealed, I put in the order. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest your regulator must handle the peak current and if that's a motor, it can be 10x the rated current if you push it. So using 2S batteries 6 to 8V is far better. for peak handling current and ultimately voltage regulation.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Just something nice about a single 18650 cell form factor.